# Can't locate DateTime.pm

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, code-metrics

Can't locate `DateTime.pm` in `@INC` (you may need to install the DateTime module)

I have installed DateTime module with these commands

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install DateTime
```

To find out where DateTime was installed I used this command

```
perldoc -ml DateTime
```

But the result was `no module found for "DateTime"`

Answer (score 1):

> **For Installing Lib DateTime on perl just type**

```
sudo apt-get install libdatetime-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Cloudwatch agent at least, make sure to install libwww-perl and libdatetime-perl

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html#mon-scripts-perl_prereq

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing monitoring scripts for cloudwatch agent.
These are the steps needed for Ubuntu

1. Install required Packages

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
sudo apt-get install libwww-perl libdatetime-perl
```

This might be the command you missed to execute, this will install the required perl packages

2. Download monitoring scripts

```
curl https://aws-cloudwatch.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.2.zip -O
```

3. Extract the files

```
unzip CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.2.zip && \
rm CloudWatchMonitoringScripts-1.2.2.zip && \
cd aws-scripts-mon
```

4. Do the IAM role configuration for your instance or create `awscreds.conf` file with your credentials
5. Do a test run

```
./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --verify --verbose
```